# Matplotlib plotting multiple datasets on same figure using setxticks python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hey there I'm pretty new to using matplotlib and am trying to plot multiple datasets on the same figure, like so:

```py
graph_df_pivot = df1.pivot_table(index='source_dt', values='num_rws', fill_value=0)
graph_df_pivot2 = df2.pivot_table(index='source_dt', values='num_rws', fill_value=0)
ax = graph_df_pivot.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 5), grid=True, title='')  # , use_index=True)
ax.set_xticks(range(0, len(graph_df_pivot.index.tolist())))
ax.set_xticklabels([str(i) for i in graph_df_pivot.index.tolist()], rotation=90)
ax.set_xticks(range(0, len(graph_df_pivot2.index.tolist())))
ax.set_xticklabels([str(i) for i in graph_df_pivot2.index.tolist()], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

This is only plotting the data from the first dataset and the second is being overlooked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any plot command for the second dataset in your code?!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I added a plot command however now I'm getting a second new graph rather than one graph with both data sets. I added `code`                     graph_df_pivot2.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20,5), grid=True, title='')#, use_index=True
`code`

Answer (score 1):

Each `plot` command by default creates a new Axes unless you pass an existing Axes object to plot on with the `ax` parameter:

```
ax = graph_df_pivot.plot(kind='line', figsize=(20, 5), grid=True, title='') 
graph_df_pivot2.plot(kind='line', ax=ax)
```